Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked a script
I'm facing this problem when i try to import firebase sdk to use them in my firefox extention

Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked a script (script-src-elem) at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.0/firebase-app.js from being executed because it violates the following directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"

manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.32",
    "description": "test",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js", "connect.js"
        ],
        "type": "module",
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/256x256_icon.png",
        "48": "icons/256x256_icon.png",
        "128": "icons/256x256_icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/256x256_icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "test"
    }
}

Any help to fix it ?

Are you trying to import the script into your background or content script? Or are you trying to inject the script into a web page?
